Updating to CrystalReports14 and calling via CLSIDFromProgID
I have a c++ application that calls a window to display a Crystal Report using Crystal Report XI like so:
CLSIDFromProgID (L"CrystalRuntime.Application.11", &CLSID_Application);
My task is to upgrade our app from Crystal Reports to Crystal Report 14.
I am not quite sure what that entails...
What is the ProgID of Crystal Reports 14, and what do I need to download to be able to call the viewer like "CrystalRuntime.Application.14"?
I understand the question is vague, and am grateful for any answeres, including pointing me to reading material to learn more about setting up crystal reports.
I have downloaded SAP Crystal Reports 2020 SAP Crystal Reports 2020 SP04 Patch 600 - ONE and SAP Crystal Reports viewer 2020 Crystal Reports Viewer 2020 SP04 Patch200, however I do not see a registry key that is something like CrystalRuntime.Application.14 or CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.14.
I also tried downloading Crystal Reports 2016 as a test,I was abe to see a registry key titled CrystalDesignRunTime.Application.13. Does CR2020 not come with a similiar key?
